# manage friends using xmpp in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone

Topic:
hi, i want to develop xmpp chat application, so far i have done with xmpp chatting, ie. sending and receiving messages to online users. but how can i add another online user as a buddy/friend ? and how can i remove friend from my friend list (using xmpp) ?? and how to know that someone has sent me a friend request (in xmpp)
Technology: iphone applcation programming
Language: Objective C

Answer (score 1):

The XMPP server manages your buddy list (roster management), so you have to send the Subscribe/Unsubscribe packets to the XMPP server to add or remove buddies. Please see the section **8.2** in XMPP RFC (rfc-3921) for the format of XMPP message that you have to send and server response that you have to handle.

Here is the link to XMPP RFC (see section 8.2)

http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html

Comment: but how i can do those things from xmpp iphone sdk ?? i have xmpp iphone sdk, i am able to send buddy request and remove from buddy request but i am not able to get requests notifications and response to request, ie. accept or reject request.....

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to send buddy request.Its working for me currently. username ot email id depends on your openfire settings.

XMPPJID *newBuddy = [XMPPJID jidWithString:@"friendsemailid or username"];

[xmppRoster addUser:newBuddy withNickname:nil];

Answer (score -1):

```
1.You can add a new friend through this code in didReceivePresence delegate
 else if  ([presenceType isEqualToString:@"subscribe"])
        {
            NSXMLElement *presenceToRequest = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"presence"];
            [presenceToRequest addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"subscribed"];
            [presenceToRequest addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [presence fromStr]]];
            [presenceToRequest addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [presence toStr]]];
            [[self xmppStream] sendElement:presenceToRequest];
        }
2.You can send friend request through XMPPRoster method
    [xmppRoster addUser:[XMPPJID jidWithString:friendJID] withNickname:friendNickName];
3.In didReceivePresence delegate you can your friend request either you want to accept or reject a friendrequest.

I hope this information helps you to solve your issues.enter code here
```

Comment: Point 3 is quite unclear can you explain more? can you provide some code?